# Does every convergent sequence have a sub-sequence whose terms comes closer than any positive sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)$ be convergent sequence of real numbers and $(y_n)$ be any sequence of positive real numbers , then is it true that there is a sub-sequence $(x_{r_n})$ such that $|x_{r_{n+1}}-x_{r_n}|<y_n , \forall n \in \mathbb N$  ?

Comment: Can you generalise the proof for the case $y_n = 2^{-n}$?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer:does there exist a proof for $2^{-n}$?

Comment: It's basically the same as the general, but that case is often used, so I thought you might have already seen it in use.

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer: No I haven't , can you please demonstrate it ?

Comment: Have you difficulties following the procedure that Igor outlined?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer:yes actually the inductive step is not coming to me

Comment: You have $r_1 <\dotsc < r_m$ such that for all $k,n \geqslant r_\mu$ you have $\lvert x_k - x_n\rvert < y_\mu$, in particular $\lvert x_{r_\mu} - x_{r_{\mu+1}}\rvert < y_\mu$ for $1\leqslant \mu < m$. Then you want to pick $r_{m+1} > r_m$ so that, whatever $r_{m+2}$ comes out to be [all you know a priori is that you will have $r_{m+2} > r_{m+1}$], you will have $\lvert x_{r_{m+1}} - x_{r_{m+2}}\rvert < y_{m+1}$. So what constraint will you place on the choice of $r_{m+1}$?

Comment: I've edited my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition of convergence (actually, by using the fact that [any convergent sequence is a cauchy sequence](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Convergent_Sequence_is_Cauchy_Sequence)), $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N\in \mathbb{N}: \forall n, m > N, |x_n - x_m| < \epsilon$. So, if you have a sequence $(y_n)$, take the $y_1$ as epsilon, choose such $N_1$ that the statement above works: $$\epsilon = y_1, \exists N_1\in\mathbb{N}: \forall n, m > N_1, |x_n - x_m| < y_1$$
Now, choose $r_1 = N_1+1$. Continue with $y_2$ the same way, just remembering that you can't choose $r_2 < r_1$:
$r_2 = N_2+1$, where
$$\exists N_2\in\mathbb{N}: \forall n, m > N_2, N_2 \geq N_1, |x_n - x_m| < y_2$$
You'll get your subsequence $(x_{r_n})$ in question.